# Argument not recognised/accesed by egrep - Shell

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

### *Egrep and Awk to output columns of a line , with a specific value for the first column*

I am to tasked to write a shell program which when ran as such

./tool.sh -f file -id id *OR* ./tool.sh -id id -f file

must output the name surname and birthdate (3 columns of the file ) for that specific id.

So far my code is structured as such :

```
    elif [ "$#" -eq 4 ];
then
        while [ "$1" != "" ];
        do
        case $1 in
             -f)
                cat < "$2" | egrep '"$4"' | awk ' {print $3 "\t" $2 "\t" $5}'
        shift 4
        ;;
             -id)
                cat < "$4" | egrep '"$2"' | awk ' {print $3 "\t" $2 "\t" $5}'
        shift 4
        esac
        done
```

(Ignoring the opening elif cause there are more subtasks for later)

My output is nothing. The program just runs.

I've tested the `cat < people.dat | egrep '125' | awk ' {print $3 "\t" $2 "\t" $5}'`

and it runs just fine.

I also had an instance where i had an output from the program while it was run like so

```
cat < "$2" | egrep '["$4"]' | awk ' {print $3 "\t" $2 "\t" $5}'
```

but it wasnt only that specific ID.

Comment: Use `egrep "$4"`. Double quotes allow variables, single quotes don't. No commands need certain types of quotes, they are purely a shell feature that are not passed to the command.

Comment: `cat < "$2" | egrep "$4" | awk ' {print $3 "\t" $2 "\t" $5}'` can be written as just one command: `awk -v OFS='\t' -v x="$4" '$0 ~ x{print $3, $2, $5}' "$2"`

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you @EdMorton

Comment: @EdMorton a bit of a followup though `awk -F'|' -v OFS='\t' -v x="$4 " '$0 ~ x{print $3, $2, $5}' "$2"` since my database is separated by '|' but know it wont type out only that specific id but also other overlapping ones 

ex. 100 will type a field with 10023 id

Comment: I was just showing you how to write your existing code using 1 command, not trying to fix its functionality. There's no sample input/output in your question for us to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`egrep "$4"` was correct instead of `egrep '["$4"]'` in 

`cat < "$2" | egrep '["$4"]' | awk ' {print $3 "\t" $2 "\t" $5}'`
```

> Double quotes allow variables, single quotes don't. No commands need
>   certain types of quotes, they are purely a shell feature that are not
>   passed to the command. mentioned by(@that other guy)